# Thunderbird addon to get rid of managing dozens and dozens of identities

Tags: thunderbird

Does anyone know of an addon that would allow me to specify an outgoing SMTP server (MTA) and that would use a fixed set of credentials to authenticate against it and then would either

- transparently create the identities for domains handled by that MTA when I press Reply such that the identity would be available and selected automatically for my response mail
- not create identities by use arbitrary aliases as `From:` field, within the set of domains handled by the MTA of course

Background: I use separate aliases ("identities" in Thunderbird parlance) for almost every web service, so it would be useful to be able to make use of these aliases, e.g. created to participate in a mailing list, without having to explicitly create an identity.

---

#### Clarification

Personally I am opposed to stating a possible solution (below) rather than the problem (above), since it narrows the perspective.

What might satisfy the above requirements, as a practical example, would be:

- some addon that collects `To:` and so on for a set of configurable domains (the domains handled by the MTA/outgoing server) and *automatically* creates these identities for me, or ...
- a "smart" addon that, when I click `Reply`, will figure out that the email was sent to `foobar@domain.tld` ... and with `@domain.tld` being a domain handled by the MTA, will adjust the `From:` header, overriding the predefined values from the drop-down menu that relies on the identities (and also preferably the respective GUI element).

In essence I want to get rid of that huge drop-down list (and believe me this only shows about one third of it), and replace it with a more dynamic method:

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you mean here, but some SMTP servers will already allow you to send mail with arbitrary From headers in Thunderbird.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: tried to clarify a little. Perhaps that helps?